# How can I update this SQL query to give the result I want?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have two tables as follow:

listings Table

```
listing_id
----------
111111
111113
```

listings_features_table

```
id  listing_id  feature_id
------------------------------
1   111111      4
2   111111      1
5   111113      9
6   111113      1
7   111113      4
```

I am trying to get only results that have all feature_id I specify. So in my case, if I specify (1, 4, 9), only listing_id `111113` has these in the feature_id column and that's what I want returned.

I've tried using IN in my query, but it's equivalent to OR, and that's why am getting a wrong result.

Following is the query am using:

```
SELECT * FROM listings_features
JOIN listings ON listings.listing_id=listings_features.listing_id
WHERE listings_features.feature_id IN (1,4,9) GROUP BY listings.listing_id
```

which gives this result:

```
id  listing_id  feature_id  listing_id
----------------------------------------------
1   111111      4           111111
5   111113      9           111113
```

is there any way I can use to get the following result instead:

```
id  listing_id  feature_id  listing_id
----------------------------------------------
5   111113      1, 4, 9     111113
```

Or shall I do that on the php level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick using `group_concat()` for the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings_features lf JOIN
     listings l
     ON l.listing_id = lf.listing_id
WHERE lf.feature_id in (1,4,9)
GROUP BY l.listing_id
HAVING group_concat(distinct lf.feature_id order by lf.feature_id) = '1,4,9';
```

If you want those features but don't care about others, then remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: you have to know the number of features and adjust the 3 accordingly. but since you know you're looking for 1,4,9, you know you have 3 so passing in a variable for the count and populating it shouldn't be difficult.

```
SELECT ID, Listing_Features.Listing_Id, group_Concat(Feature_ID), Listings.Listing_Id 
FROM listings_features
JOIN listings ON listings.listing_id=listings_features.listing_id
WHERE listings_features.feature_id IN (1,4,9) GROUP BY listings.listing_id
GROUP BY Listing_Features.ID, Listing_Features.Listing_Id, Listings.Listing_Id FROM listings_features
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

Comment: 1. GROUP_CONCAT(feature_id SEPARATOR ', ') 2. a NATURAL JOIN should make it simpler?

Comment: Tried the query and it gave an error, edited some typos and now am using this query:

SELECT id, listings_features.listing_id, group_Concat(feature_id), listings.listing_id
FROM listings_features
JOIN listings ON listings.listing_id=listings_features.listing_id
WHERE listings_features.feature_id IN (1,4,9) GROUP BY listings.listing_id
GROUP BY listings_features.id, listings_features.listing_id, listings.listing_id FROM listings_features
HAVING count(*) = 3

but it's still giving an error: #1064

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY listings_features.id, listings_features.listing_id, listings.listing_id' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Listings_features.Listing_ID), group_concat(Feature_ID),  MAX(Listings.Listing_ID) from Listings_Features
inner join Listings USING (listing_id)
WHERE Listings_Features.feature_id IN(1,4,9) 
GROUP BY ID;
```

- Probably messed up on the table names. I listings and listing all look the same...but generally...

Comment: Run it and it gave me:
    id MAX(listings_features.listing_id) group_concat(feature_id) MAX(listings.listing_id)
    1 111111 4 111111
    2 111111 1 111111
    5 111113 9 111113
    6 111113 1 111113
    7 111113 4 111113